# MySQL backup process hit with a Win32Exception that the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows, winforms, win32exception

I am hit with a mysterious win32exception here when i was attempting to do a mysqldump(backup) to backup my database on a windows form , .Net Framework 4.0, Visual Studio 2010 on a x64 Windows 8.0 machine.

All went fine except for this process where it crashes mysteriously where they said that the system cannot find the file specified.

Any direction on how I can solve this? Thanks!

[image: The place where I was hit with an error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [UseShellExecute=false](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In this context, the MSDN specifies that the FileName property should be a fully qualified path to the executable. So, just writing `mysqldump.exe` as the filename is not enough to start the process.

I recommend to set also the [WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the path where the mysql binaries are installed because, if the process launched needs some local installed resources, withoud a WorkingDirectory set you could have hard times to understand errors about files not found or missing configuration files.

Comment: Surely there are four options and option #1 is specify the full path of `mysqldump.exe` ?

Comment: @ta.speot.is you have a point here. Initially I thought that specofying a full path for mysqldump was not a good idea, but then I noticed the UseShellExecute=false and this change everything.